# Visual Studio 2015 N Unit Test Runs 3 Times

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I have created a Selenium WebDriver Test In which I am using N Unit to Run the Test from Test Explorer. The test is running fine but it runs a total of 3 times. I have tried do some self diagnosis but cant seem to find a solution. If this helps here are the references I am calling in my solution. I tried to narrow the list as much as possible but it continues to repeat regardless.

[image]

Comment: From my experience, the root cause is NUnit test adapter. Can you disable the adapter and run test again?

Comment: @Buaban Interestingly enough I removed "NUnitTestAdapter" and left only "NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework" this brought my test count down to 2. Any idea how to narrow it down to one test?

Comment: Check to see if the adapter is installed as both a nuget package and a vsix extension. VS2015 handles this differently from its predecessors.

Comment: Thank you Both That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Credit to both @Buaban and @Charlie.      Looks like I was running the test from 3 places:

NUnitTestAdapter (vsix extention)

NUnitTestAdapter (nuget package)

NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework (nuget package)

I removed the first 2 items and kept the .WithFramework nuget package.